# What can NOT be described by a PCRE regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, computation-theory

I am using a lot of regular expressions and stumbled over the question what actually can **not** be described by a regex.

First example that came to my mind was matching a string like `XOOXXXOOOOXXXXX...`. This would be a string consisting of an alternating sequence of `X`'s and `O`'s where each subpart consisting only of the character `X` or `O` is longer than the previsous sequence of the other character.

Can anybody explain what is the formal limit of a regex? I know this might be a rather academic question but I'm a curious person ;-)

**Edit**
As I am a php guy I am especially interested in regex described by PCRE standard as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php
I know that PCRE allows a lot of things that are not part of the original regular expressions like back references.

Mathcing of balanced parentheses seems to be one example that can not be matched by regular expressions in general but it **can** be matched using PCRE (see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd12b580bb9ad7a19e226219d5146322a41c6e47 for live example):

```
$data = array('()', '(())', ')(', '(((()', '(((((((((())))))))))', '()()');    
$regex = '/^((?:[^()]|\((?1)\))*+)$/';

foreach($data as $d) {
  echo "$d matched by regex: " . (preg_match($regex, $d) ? 'yes' : 'no') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: You should also define how strictly you want the term "regular expression" to be defined - modern regex engines have features to make them context-aware and support recursion; two things "real" regexes can't do.

Comment: You're right. I'll update my question.

Comment: You must be interested in what PCRE cannot do compared to other regex flavors, or just what it cannot do? I do not see any practical point: regex is a kind of a text parser, so it cannot increment numbers, it does not know if an object is null, etc. Do you mean you want a list of *string patterns* that cannot be matched with PCRE? It is not possible to remove N amount of characters when followed by an N amount of backspaces, but  it is possible to remove N amount of same characters when followed by N amount of backspaces.

Comment: Looking for a simple and comprehensive example of what a PCRE can not match. The "standard example" to demonstrate what a "normal" regex can not match seems to be balanced series of parentheses but that can be matched by PCRE. Just looking for a scenario where I can give a verbal description of the sequence trying to match but can't match it using PCRE. Examples like e.g. a PCRE matching all prime numbers would not be very satisfying as nobody could give a real description of how those strings would look like.

Comment: The academic answer would be that *regular expressions* cannot match *"irregular" languages*, though in practice some can (extended regexen) and in actuality they're often used to do just that ("parse" HTML with regexen, shudder)...

Comment: It's actually easy to write a PCRE that matches all prime numbers in "base 1" notation (where the number is represented as just a sequence of `1`'s of the appropriate length): `^(?!(1{2,})\1+$)`. I'm not sure whether you can write a PCRE that matches all prime numbers in decimal notation, but it wouldn't surprise me. (Note that for any individual *n*, the set of decimal representations of nontrivial multiples of *n* is a regular language even in the CS sense. The hard part is expressing the union of all of those languages.)

Comment: @ruakh That expression will match any sequence of 1s. Describing the "appropriate" length of such a sequence is where the difficulty comes from ;-) A working example of the regex in action can be found at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd930e4bbd97d598ab08ad3abdb7059e4072fcb9

Comment: @maxhb: Why don't you actually test the regex? (Why link to a sandbox, but not use it yourself?) Here's a demonstration: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d8943f4f3cab49167bb3086d7bffde18af353e9

Comment: @maxhb: That said, that regex matches any string that's not the base-1 representation of a composite number, so it's not 100% correct; to specifically match base-1 representations of prime numbers, I should append `1{2,}$` to restrict it to base-1 representations of integers >= 2: `^(?!(1{2,})\1+$)1{2,}$`.

Comment: My fault, I was testing the regex against 1,2,3... and not 1, 11, 111... :-( For those interested in understanding how the regex works, read this blogpost http://www.noulakaz.net/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First example that came to my mind was matching a string like `XOOXXXOOOOXXXXX...`. This would be a string consisting of an alternating sequence of `X`'s and `O`'s where each subpart consisting only of the character `X` or `O` is longer than the previsous sequence of the other character.

Yes, that can be done.

---

1. To match a non-empty sequence of x's, followed by a greater number of o's, we can use an approach similar to that of the balanced-parentheses regex:

   ```
   (x(?1)?o)o+
   ```
2. To match a string of x's and o's such that any sequence of x's is followed by a longer sequence of o's (except optionally at the very end), we can build on pattern #1:

   ```
   ^o*(?:(x(?1)?o)o+)*x*$
   ```
3. And of course, we'll also need a variant of pattern #2 with x's and o's flipped:

   ```
   ^x*(?:(o(?1)?x)x+)*o*$
   ```
4. To match a string of x's and o's that meet both of the above criteria, we can convert pattern #2 to a positive lookahead assertion, and renumber the capture-group in pattern #3:

   ```
   ^(?=o*(?:(x(?1)?o)o+)*x*$)x*(?:(o(?2)?x)x+)*o*$
   ```

---

As for the main question . . . I'm confident that a PCRE can match any context-free language, since the support for `(?n)` *outside* of the *n*th capture-group means that you can basically create a subroutine for each of your non-terminals. For example, this context-free grammar:

- *S* → *aTb*
- *S* → ε
- *T* → *cSd*
- *T* → *eTf*

can be written as:

- capture-group #1 (*S*) → `(a(?2)b|)`
- capture-group #2 (*T*) → `(c(?1)d|e(?2)f)`

To assemble that into a single regex, we can just concatenate them all, but appending `{0}` after all but the start non-terminal, and then add `^` and `$`:

```
^(a(?2)b|)(c(?1)d|e(?2)f){0}$
```

But as you saw from your first example, PCREs can match some non-context-free languages as well. (Another example is *a*<sup>*n*</sup>*b*<sup>*n*</sup>*c*<sup>*n*</sup>, which is a classic example of a non-context-free language. You can match it with PCRE by combining a PCRE for *a*<sup>*n*</sup>*b*<sup>*n*</sup>*c*<sup>*m*</sup> with a PCRE for *a*<sup>*m*</sup>*b*<sup>*n*</sup>*c*<sup>*n*</sup> using a forward lookahead assertion. Although the intersection of two regular languages is necessarily regular, the intersection of two context-free languages is *not* necessarily context-free; but the intersection of the languages defined by two PCREs *can* be defined by a PCRE.)

Comment: I wonder if you know how PCRE can remove the same number of any characters as the number of backspaces after them. `str = "\bNewqaz\b\b\b car!!!\b\b\b."` -> `str = "New car."` Perhaps, there is something I overlooked some months ago :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Where did the `\b` at the start of `str` go?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: If that `\b` was just a mistake, then -- you can use the regex `([^\b](?1)*[\b])` to match (and therefore to replace) balanced pairs of non-backspace characters and backspace characters.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and thumbs up for the `^(?=o*(?:(x(?1)*o)o)*x*$)x*(?:(o(?2)*x)x)*o*$` regex ;-)

Comment: @ruakh: That's it, that point is that I applied `?` quantifier to the subroutine call. `*` definitely resolves that. +1.

Comment: You should use `(?(DEFINE)`...`)` instead of `(`...`){0}` to, well...*define* rules - that's exactly what's it's for. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#define).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Good to know, thanks! (I think I'll leave my answer as-is, though, since I'm not recommending a practice, but rather just demonstrating a formalism. The advantage of `{0}` is that I don't need to explain what it means.)

Answer (score 1):

The set of all languages that can be recognized by a regular expression is called, not surprisingly, "[regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)".

The next most complicated languages are the [context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language).  They cannot be parsed by any regular expression.  The standard example is "all balanced parentheses" -- so "()()" and "(())" but not "(()".

Another good example of a context-free language is HTML.

Comment: `^((?:\((?1)*\))*)$` in PCRE [matches balanced parentheses](https://regex101.com/r/yY4mJ9/1).

Comment: FTFA: "a regular language is a formal language that can be expressed using a regular expression, in the strict sense of the latter notion used in theoretical computer science *(as opposed to many regular expressions engines provided by modern programming languages, which are augmented with features that allow recognition of languages that cannot be expressed by a classic regular expression)*."

Comment: I do know that. OP isn't asking about formal regular expressions, but PCRE. He clarified that after my asking him (and after your answer).

Comment: Yeah, the question is clear, but I don't know of (and could not find online) any formal analysis of the languages possible with PCRE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have definitive evidence that any of these are impossible with things like recursion, balancing groups, self-referencing groups, and appending text to the string being tested. I would be glad to be proven wrong on any or all of these, as I would learn something!

1. It's pretty bad at math.

For example, I do not believe it is possible using PCRE, to detect a sequence of numbers that is ascending: that is, to match "1 2 7 97 315 316..." but not "127 97 315 316..."

2. I'm not sure it's possible to even match a sequence *contiguously increasing from 1,* like "1 2 3...", without exhaustively listing all possibilities like `/1( 2( 3(...)?)?)?/` up to the max length you wish to check.

Thee are hacks to make it work by adding known text to the string under test (eg http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-line-numbers.html works by adding a series of numbers to the end of the file). But as raw regex, simple math is only possible by brute-forcing.

3. Another example which I believe it will fail at is "match any sequence which sums to N".

So for N=4, it should match `4`, `3 1`, `1 3`, `2 2`, `1 1 1 1`, `2 1 1`, `1 2 1`, `1 1 2`, `1 1 1 1`, which looks like you could brute-force it, until you realize it also has to match `4 -12 11 0 1`.

4. In the same manner, I don't think you could have it analyze an equation using SI units, and verify whether the units balanced on both sides of the equation. For example, "10N=2kg*5ms^-1". Never mind checking the values, just checking the units are correct.
5. Then there're all the classes of problems that no computer program can currently accomplish, such as "check if a string has been correctly title cased in English" which would require a context-sensitive natural language parser to correctly detect the different senses of "like" in "Time Flies like an Arrow But Fruit Flies Like a Banana".